# Whether "and" is needed

Tags: coordination

> In spoken and informal written English "that" is usually left out after reporting verbs and adjectives. It is less often left out after nouns. ( Usage note in Oxford dictionary about "that")

Does "In spoken and informal written English"  apply to the second sentence？  Someone argues that it doesn't: the apply-to-the-second-sentence idea can only be conveyed when  the period is replaced by a "and".  What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of the *syntactically* implied meaning, I'd say it's a racing certainty that *in the real world, in formal contexts **as well***, the relativiser ***that*** is less often omitted after nouns. Though it might be more accurate to say it's ***sometimes*** rather than ***usually*** omitted after verbs and adjectives in formal contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thanks for the comment.  Maybe I didn't make it clear. " After noun"  was referring to examples like:  I didn't know the fact that ....  It is the conjunction "that"  that is talked about.

Comment: your conjunction, my relativiser. I'm sure [that] it's the same thing, even if someone argues [that] it isn't. But ***the fact that*** is an established collocation [that] you can't casually interfere with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is  "yes it does apply". It is a natural follow on from the first sentence. If it didn't apply then you would need to qualify it by something like

> On the other hand it is less often left out after nouns *in both
> spoken and written English*.

Agreed substituting "and" for the period would also work, but you would probably write

> ... verbs and adjectives *and* less often after nouns.

omitting the repeat of the verb (to leave {out}) which applies to the usage in all circumstances.